# JTables cell alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have two `JTable`s aligned horizontally inside `JScrollBar`.  When I select a cell in the first `JTable` I would like the corresponding cell on the other `JTable` to be aligned.

What I'm doing is that I use, each time a cell in the first `JTable` is selected, the `JTable.getCellRect()` method to get the the y position of each cell and then use `JTable.scrollRectToVisible(firstJTableCell)`.  The cell in the second `JTable` becomes then visible, but I would like to know how to align it with the selected cell in the first `JTable`.  
I have a way to know which cell to select in the second `JTable` when a cell is selected in the first `JTable`. What I would like to know, is how to align two JTables cell programatically.

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.  You have `JTable`s inside a `JScrollBar`?  And you want to align the cells?  What do you mean by align?

Comment: Aligned horizontally, at the same distance from the top of the screen.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE, because answer by @MadProgrammer (+1) could be / (but) couldn'd be proper for description in your question,

Comment: @mKorbel That sounds like most of my answers!  If you can't dazzle with brilliance, baffle with bull s***t ;)

Comment: if the (view) rowCount and indices are the same in both tables, you can use the same adjustmentModel in both vertical scrollbars

Comment: no idea why moving with JScrollBars, not to use AdjustmmentListener you don't needed that, never, JTable can be sorted or filtered, search selected value in second model, convertModelToView, toggle with Selection (I'm will be to use one the same model for both JTables)

Comment: @kleopatra rowCount and indices are the same, but rowHeight are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways to achieve the same result, essentally though, you can just use an `AdjustmentListener` and a `ListSelectionListener` to monitor changes to the `JScrollPane`s and `JTable`s and sync those results back to the other table (based on the source of the original event)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentEvent;
import java.awt.event.AdjustmentListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SyncedTables {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SyncedTables();
    }

    public SyncedTables() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTable left;
        private JTable right;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
            left = new JTable(createTableModel("L"));
            right = new JTable(createTableModel("R"));

            left.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            right.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

            JScrollPane leftScrollPane = new JScrollPane(left);
            JScrollPane rightScrollPane = new JScrollPane(right);

            AdjustmentHandler ah = new AdjustmentHandler(leftScrollPane, rightScrollPane);

            leftScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(ah);
            leftScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(ah);
            rightScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(ah);
            rightScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(ah);

            SelectionHandler sh = new SelectionHandler(left, right);
            left.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(sh);
            right.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(sh);

            add(leftScrollPane);
            add(rightScrollPane);

        }

        protected TableModel createTableModel(String prefix) {
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 50);
            for (int row = 0; row < 100; row++) {
                Object[] rowData = new Object[50];
                for (int col = 0; col < 50; col++) {
                    rowData[col] = prefix + "-" + row + "x" + col;
                }
                model.addRow(rowData);
            }
            return model;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    public class SelectionHandler implements ListSelectionListener {

        private JTable left;
        private JTable right;
        private boolean ignore;

        public SelectionHandler(JTable left, JTable right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!ignore) {
                ignore = true;
                if (e.getSource() == left.getSelectionModel()) {
                    sync(left, right);
                } else if (e.getSource() == right.getSelectionModel()) {
                    sync(left, right);
                }
                ignore = false;
            }
        }

        protected void sync(JTable master, JTable slave) {
            slave.clearSelection();
            int[] selectedRows = master.getSelectedRows();
            for (int row : selectedRows) {
                slave.addRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
            }
            int[] selectedColumns = master.getSelectedColumns();
            for (int cols : selectedColumns) {
                slave.addColumnSelectionInterval(cols, cols);
            }
        }
    }

    public class AdjustmentHandler implements AdjustmentListener {

        private JScrollPane left;
        private JScrollPane right;
        private boolean ignore;

        public AdjustmentHandler(JScrollPane left, JScrollPane right) {
            this.left = left;
            this.right = right;
        }

        @Override
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            if (!ignore) {
                ignore = true;
                Container parent = ((Component) e.getSource()).getParent();
                if (parent == left) {
                    sync(left, right);
                } else if (parent == right) {
                    sync(right, left);
                }
                ignore = false;
            }
        }

        protected void sync(JScrollPane master, JScrollPane slave) {
            slave.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(master.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue());
            slave.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(master.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you code, but it is not the way to go in my case.  Sorry to update my message so late, but I didn't really have time before.